# Last empty line and ifstream::operator>> (C++)

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, ifstream

I have a question about the ifstream::operator>> behavior in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    ifstream inFile("test.txt");
    string buffer;
    while (!inFile.eof()) {
        inFile >> buffer;
        cout << buffer << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code works perfectly well if the last line of test.txt is not empty, for instance :

```
One two
Three four
Five six
```

However if test.txt is written like that :

```
One two
Three four
Five six
(empty line)
```

The `cout` will display two "six" strings.
Is it a problem related to the \r\n of Windows or something like that ?
I use Microsoft VC++ 2010.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Your entire problem boils down to this:  `while (!inFile.eof())` <-- Don't do that!

Comment: ... while (inFile >> buffer) ...

Seems to work fine.
As explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong, thanks Zac.

Answer (score 3):

Using `stream.eof()` for loop control us normally wrong: you **always** want to check the result **after** reading:

```
while (inFile >> buffer) {
    ...
}
```

The formatted read will start with skipping leading whitespace. After that, the string extractor will read non-whitespace characters. If there is no such character, the extraction fails and the stream converts to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Before the read it wasn't EOF yet. But last read action has failed due to EOF reach.

You can use `fail` to check if your last read failed:

```
int main () {
    ifstream inFile("test.txt");
    string buffer;
    while (!inFile.eof()) {
        inFile >> buffer;
       /**EDIT**/
       if(!inFile.fail()){
            cout << buffer << endl;
        }else{
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I try your code the inFile.gcount() always returns 0.
I guess that the operator<< doesn't increment the gcount.

Comment: You do not want to do this kind of operation using `while (!istream::eof())`.  It will always make your code far more complicated than it would be otherwise.

Comment: You were right my mistake. I've edited the answer. for this you can use `if(!inFile.fail())`